# Hard vs Soft Hierarchical Address Derivation

Tags: parity, nodes

I'm using parity as node/JSONRPC and I'm generating a HD wallet with it.
Basically I have one address and, according to the Parity documentation, I can generate a new address with this command:

```
parity_deriveAddressIndex
```

The documentation says:

> Derive new address from given account address using hierarchical
>   derivation (sequence of 32-bit integer indices).

It takes the followint Parameters:

```
Address - Account address to export.
String - Password to the account.
Array - Hierarchical derivation sequence of index and type (soft or hard). E.g. [{index:1,type:"hard"},{index:2,type:"soft"}].
Boolean - Flag indicating if the account should be saved.
```

I am a bit confused with the third paremeter: what is the difference between using soft and hard hierarchical derivations?

Comment: have you found any answer to this ?